# Где лучше вставлять множество копий текста - в PHP или в JS?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

На моей странице делается выборка из базы данных:

```
<?php
$row = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query('SELECT * FROM `myTable`);
?>
```

Какой вариант лучше (быстрее и будет меньше тормозить), если таких выборок будет более 1000?

1 вариант:

```
<span id="textA"><?php echo $row['A']; ?></span>
<span id="textAA"><?php echo $row['A']; ?></span>
<span id="textAAA"><?php echo $row['A']; ?></span>
```

2 вариант:

```
<span id="textA"><?php echo $row['A']; ?></span>
<script>
    document.getElementById("textAA").textContent =
            document.getElementById("textA").textContent;
    document.getElementById("textAAA").textContent =
            document.getElementById("textA").textContent;
```

... и так далее.

Comment: Долго объяснять. Там целая система.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не буду спрашивать зачем вам это нужно, но первый вариант несомненно лучше. Потому что если это делать через php то для сервера без разницы сколько выводить переменных, и время генерации страницы увеличится на такую единицу времени, которой в даже в высокоточных расчетах можно пренебречь.

Второй вариант будет тормозить все скрипты у пользователя, и может просто повесить страницу.

Comment: А вы отчетливо понимаете, что в статье явно сказано, что `.textContent` лучше `.innerText`?

Answer (score 0):

Оба варианта плохи тем, как написан код. Непонятно, почему не используется цикл, и почему в случае JS вы каждый раз достаете значение из DOM-элемента, вместо того чтобы хранить его в переменной.

А по сути вопроса - на практике используется подстановка данных в шаблон как на сервере, так и в браузере, все зависит от организации веб-приложения.

Answer (score 0):

Если копий много и они большие, то лучше не гонять лишний объём по сети, а воспользоваться клиентским скриптом. И помести строку в переменную и добавляй новые элементы, а не пихай элементы заранее в разметку.

В любом случае, исполнение скрипта на клиенте должно снизить нагрузку на сервер, но не думаю, что для тебя это существенно.

Ну и само собой, если в браузере окажется отключен js, то добавление элементов не сработает. Если элементы нужны и при отключенном js, то однозначно надо добавлять на сервере.

Answer (score -1):

1 вариант будет быстрее, а циклы сделают систему «тормознутой».

Comment: "В любом случае, исполнение скрипта на клиенте должно снизить нагрузку на сервер, но не думаю, что для тебя это существенно." И вопрос зачем вам js? Скрипт не большой, делайте через php + могут и вправду отключить js, а php не отключишь:)